# How can I predict whether an LCD clock will "fade" over time?

Tags: electronic-items

Like many people, I take a small travel alarm clock with me when I travel. As a matter of personal preference, I don't like to use my phone for this and I don't like analog clocks with hands. I want a digital display and a physical snooze button. This sort of thing:

[image]

Every few years, I buy such a clock, and for a year or two I really like it and am glad I replaced the old one. But then the numbers become hard to read. They aren't as dark, I think. Sometimes I can read them if I hold the clock at just the right angle. Generally the button you push to light up the background just makes it worse. Eventually I end up having to replace the clock, and the cycle repeats.

**What is the property of the clocks I choose that causes this?** Would I be better choosing an entirely different technology other than these black-segments-on-a-grey-background clocks? Replacing my clock means learning different gestures to turn it off or snooze it, or to confirm that it's set before going to sleep, and this has led to mis-set alarms, failure to wake, and taking too long to turn it off when the alarm starts beeping in my bag. To prevent this I would like to buy one clock that I can use for a decade or more instead of a new clock every few years.

Comment: it is a **travel** alarm. The conditions for its use are entirely different than those for an alarm clock you use at home. In fact I never use these clocks at home and they typically sit in my briefcase set to a different time zone all the time.

Comment: Yes and some people use suitcases as furniture but we have suitcase questions here anyway

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on electronics SE.

Comment: a site that doesn't exist, @chx - I checked.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You said you don't like phones, but they keep current when you change timezone and you can keep a list of cities which time you want to track. I haven't owned a watch or clock in years

Comment: @blackbird57 first, they don't switch to local time if your sim does not work there (common for me and I don't always buy a local sim), second, they don't have a stand or a physical snooze button, third, the noises they make are not alarm clock noises to me. Not that it is relevant - I don't want to use my phone.

Comment: @chx http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267275/why-doesnt-electronics-show-up-in-the-dropdown

Comment: All of this banter aside- I find that LCD clocks usually have only one cause for the symptoms you describe: low battery. A basic, monochrome LCD screen should last for a long time- like decades. Traveling tends to suspiciously drain batteries. To alleviate some of your problems, perhaps add a new habit of removing the batteries from the clock when it is not in use.

Comment: @chx The "Electronics" SE site is not a Q&A for consumer electronics. The site you suggest actually states "Don't ask about: Shopping or buying recommendations" as well as "Don't ask about: Consumer electronics...". Although this question is not entirely on-topic, it is not off-topic.

Comment: I would suggest something like this: http://www.amazon.com/RCA-Digital-Alarm-Clock-Display/dp/B007T0W5CA/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1443825937&sr=8-2&keywords=alarm+clock
or: 
http://www.amazon.com/Jensen-JCR-235-Alarm-Projection-Clock/dp/B00JSYG68E/ref=pd_sim_23_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=1TA8D4C647D2Z3HXXYT9&dpID=41nquxv49aL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR159%2C160_

Comment: I had a Timex travel clock that lasted me 12+ years of heavy use (lots of travel including camping) before the lcd issue you described cropped up.  It has sadly been discontinued, but apparently there are still some to be had in Canada: https://www.expeditionshoppe.com/index.php/travel-gear/timex-travel-alarm-clock.html

Comment: @paulmz although the old battery didn't test as flat, putting a new one has in fact given the clock a new lease on life and made the numbers readable once again. If only this were deemed a travel question (**travel alarm clock**, you know) I could have upvoted and accepted your answer. I hope my gratitude is enough :-)

Comment: Works for me. Glad to help.